# age(date, date) inconsistent behaviour

Tags: postgresql

How does the `age(date, date)` function work? The outputs in the following examples seem inconsistent to me.

Query 1:

```
select 
    extract(epoch from ('sept 10 2013'::timestamp - 'july 1 2013'::timestamp)),     
    extract(epoch from 'sept 10 2013'::timestamp) - extract(epoch from 'july 1 2013'::timestamp),
    extract(epoch from age('sept 10 2013', 'july 1 2013'))
```

Output 1:

```
6134400 | 6134400 | 5961600
```

It's a 2 day difference:

```
 (6134400 - 5961600) / 60 / 60 / 24 = 2
```

Query 2:

```
select 
    extract(epoch from ('sept 10 2013'::timestamp - 'sept 1 2013'::timestamp)),
    extract(epoch from 'sept 10 2013'::timestamp) - extract(epoch from 'sept 1 2013'::timestamp),
    extract(epoch from age('sept 10 2013', 'sept 1 2013'))
```

Output 2:

```
777600 | 777600 | 777600
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing yourself by looking at epochs/timestamps instead of the underlying intervals. Things might become clearer if we throw out the epochs:

```
=> select '2013-09-10'::timestamp - '2013-07-01'::timestamp, age('2013-09-10', '2013-07-01');
 ?column? |      age      
----------+---------------
 71 days  | 2 mons 9 days
```

Both the timestamp subtraction and the `age` give you `interval`s, however the subtraction is giving an interval of only days whereas the `age` call gives you an interval with separate month and day components. The difference is visible if we apply the intervals to a timestamp:

```
=> select current_timestamp + interval '71 days', current_timestamp + interval '2 mons 9 days';
           ?column?            |           ?column?            
-------------------------------+-------------------------------
 2014-06-19 11:37:59.698558-07 | 2014-06-18 11:37:59.698558-07
```

There's a one day difference because of the months that get crossed.

The [`age` docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html) say:

> Subtract arguments, producing a "symbolic" result that uses years and months

and that's exactly what you're getting. The [timestamp subtraction docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html) don't explicitly tell you what sort of interval you'll get back but you do get days instead of separate year, month, and day components:

```
=> select '2014-09-10'::timestamp - '2013-07-01'::timestamp;
 ?column? 
----------
 436 days
```

The interval that `age` gives you will cover a different timespan than the days-only interval that timestamp subtraction gives you because not all months have the same number of days.

What does `extract(epoch ...)` do with an interval? Well, the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) says:

> [...] for `interval` values, the total number of seconds in the interval

That's a little ambiguous. The number of seconds in an interval can depends on when the interval starts and when it ends: you could cross a DST boundary, the number of seconds in a month depends on which month (and year in the case of February) you're looking at, ...

Using `extract(epoch ...)` on an `interval` isn't terribly useful if your interval has a month component so `extract(epoch from age(...))` isn't a good idea.